# Java : Inheritance and Basic Design Optimization

Tags: java, inheritance

I have a Java TCP service which has inheritance used in below manner.
Java Service takes Json as input , processes it and then returns a Json. Processing is distributed across classes like B and C. A creates their Objects and gets their work done. Instead of Passing inputJson to B and C , i have stored it Container class so that it can be easily used by child classes of Container.
I am sure there is a better way to redesign it. Please guide.
(Note : In real , There are more classes like B,C and container contains more properties that are used by doB1() and doC1() etc)

```
//Pseudo
Class Main(){

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        return new A().a1(inputJson);   
    }

}

Class Container{
    JsonNode input;
    JsonNode output;
}

Class A extends Container{

    private JsonNode a1(inputJson)
    {
        input = inputJson;

        B bObject = new B();
        bObject.doB1();

        C cObject = new C();
        cObject.doC1();

        return output;
    }

}

Class B extends Container{
    public void doB1()
    {
        //prepares and updates part of output using input
    }
}

Class C extends Container{
    public void doC1()
    {
        //prepares and updates part of output using input
    }
}
```

Comment: do the processing methods in A, B, C etc have the same name, returntype and parameters?

Comment: Different names , different returntypes.. no polymorphism.

Comment: Your code does not work like you think it does - extending will not copy JSON from A to B and C, you will have to pass it anyway. I suggest you try to play around with basic concepts and _then_ think about optimization.

Comment: I am getting JsonInput in A , B , C.. Each A , B , C are child of Container class in which A stores the input. so B and C can use them.. So yes , i can access them. Question seems basic but would be nice if u can suggest some way to implement the same.

Comment: those doB1 and doC1 must NOT be of type private as they are being used from Class A. also I think something is missing, how do you instantiate Container input field of say B or C? clearly the value you are putting inside a1 method would not go inside the inherited input field of B or C just because it inherits the properties of Container class. Are you sure this code is working as per your requirement?

Comment: 1)Yes ,  doB1 and doC1 are public . 2) I dont have to instantiate Container input for B , C bcoz they are child class of container class and they can access Container fields directly. 3) Yes , i know .. thats one of the problem. (i.e. In a1 input = inputJson; sets properly but i am unable to use it in doB1 and doC1 ) i have some solutions for the same but not sure about the ideal one. Can you suggest one?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? There might be different approaches for different problems.

Comment: I have class A that calls B,C for processing. Input Json and some intermediate objects values created by B,C are used heavily inside B,C across many function calls.  I wish to 1) avoid passing inputJson and those intermediate  variables to all internal function calls in B,C 2) call functions of B , C from A.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this is what you are looking for, it eliminates the single Container superclass you need.
Using it could be as simple as `C.process(B.Process(A.create()));`
Of course you would need to make sure that every class return a `JsonNode`, but that functionality already seems to be there seeing your container.

```
interface Processor {
    public JsonNode process(JsonNode input);
}

Class A {
    public JsonNode create() {...}
}

Class B implements Processor {
    public JsonNode process(JsonNode input) {
        // logics
        return output;
    }
}

Class C implements Processor {
    public JsonNode process(JsonNode input) {
        // logics
        return output;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks .. Looks better but still I am trying to avoid passing input to process functions of B,C to cut down on parameter list that i need to pass to them. Thats y i created a Container class to store the input and other frequently used objects. And i am inheriting B , C to container so that they can get a to input as well as those frequently used objects.  Any more suggestions? Thanks

Comment: Passing arguments is the way to go. Unless you have a lot more than 6, in which case I would suggest to create a `Processable` class, which you can then use as parameter.

Comment: Yes. But i was thinking (Passing the Processable class as parameter Vs inheriting Processable class). There are many internal calls in B and C and if i chose passing object then i would have to pass it almost every function. So i chose inheritance. The Processible class of your case is like container class of my case .. and childs B,C are using its properties very conveniently via inheritance. I know there are drawbacks to this approach (Like my functions are not generic )and that is why i am looking for a better designing.

Comment: Initially , properties present in Container were set in A .. and B and C used extend A. There was no container class.In the begnining  doB1 and doC1() were static and so were properties in A so inheritance was not hurting. I recently had to remove inheritance of B->A and C->A bcoz i needed to call doB1() and doC1() from A and this cannot be done from a1() as A is parent of B and  C.

Comment: @JayTeli The fact that `A` and `B` extend `Container` doesn't mean that it gets its properties. `A` and `B` are classes. When you do `new A()` you create an object, which has the structure of `Container`, but it's properties are set to default, which are `null`. When you do `new B()` you create another object with the same structure as `Container` with its properties set to `null`. Classes are NOT objects!

Comment: I agree. Can u suggest implementable design to my problem?

Comment: @JayTeli take a look decorator design pattern,  Dr lvol's suggestion is also decorator (like) solution.